# How to pass additional parameters to ajax call back function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a ajax call as follows:

```
util.AjaxCall(url,successCallbackFunction,errorCallbackFunction);

function successCallbackFunction(result){
   //Ajax returns result
}
```

Everything is working fine, except I have to pass one of my own parameter to be available on 'successCallbackFunction'.

Something like

```
function successCallbackFunction(result, passedParameter){
}
```

How can I do that ?

Note: I don't have access to util.AjaxCall source code ( I am not authorized to change that code).

Comment: Use a closure / anonymous function.

Comment: what is `passedParameter` is it created by you or by the `util.AjaxCall()` method

Comment: @SLaks: If I use that how can I combine my own parameter with the ajax returned data?

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Created by me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bind`:

```
util.AjaxCall(url,
              successCallbackFunction.bind(this, passedParameter),
              errorCallbackFunction);
```

*<sup>The first parameter is the functions scope and in your case propably negligible.</sup>*

Which will then trigger your `successCallbackFunction` with an additional (prepended) parameter:

```
function successCallbackFunction(passedParameter, result){}
```

Comment: what about Ajax result ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fbind according to this article the arguments are prepended to the arguments normally sent to the callback. Also certain versions of IE do not support currying via bind.

Comment: Yes, of course they are prepended, thanks for the correction @Gabriel

Comment: @Gabriel -- they do. You just have to write a `bind` method yourself, and if the IE is old enough, it probably shouldn't be on the `Function.prototype` so much as `window.bindFunc`, and also, if you intend to use it for event-listeners, you need to jump through further hoops to ensure proper propagation of `this` elements...  I don't miss working predominantly with IE6-8...

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you are sending/receiving Ajax request you exchange data with JSON format.
so that you can receive your data as JSON Object.

For example if the line below is the return result via Ajax call

```
{"firstname":"john","lastname":"doe"}
```

then you can retreive your data by

```
function successCallbackFunction(result){
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);  // if you are using Jquery if not use eval
  // var obj = eval(result);           // this is not recommeneded for security issue.
  var firstname = obj.firstname;
  var lastname = obj.lastname;
}
```

Comment: Or if you are using modern browsers, simply call `JSON.parse()`